# VBA Get Unique values from RegEx.Execute

Tags: regex, excel, vba

How can I filter a `RegEx.Execute()` to only contain the unique matches?

Currently I have this:

```
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)
```

And I know I can loop through the elements with:

```
For i = 0 To allMatches.Count - 1

Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question. Although a `for each next` is cleaner and may be faster. Then add to a scripting dictionary. Keys are unique so it will error if already in the dictionary.

```
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
On Error Resume Next
For each line in AllMatches
    Dict.Add Line, ""
    If Err.Number <> 0 then err.clear
Next    

For Each thing in Dict.Keys()
    Outp.writeline thing
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Uses a Dictionary but without the unnecessary error handling

```
Sub recut()
allMatches = Array("apple", "bannana", "apple", "pear")
Set objdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each objmatch In allMatches
    If Not objdict.exists(objmatch) Then objdict.Add objmatch, 1
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group around the match, and use a back-reference in the negative look-ahead.

Imagine we want unique 3-digit groups from `123 456 789 123 456 789`: `123`, `456` and `789`. We need to place `[0-9]{3}` into a capturing group like `([0-9]{3})`, and then check if there is no repetition of this captured group later in the string. So, that we only capture the last duplicate group.

```
([0-9]{3})(?!.*?\1.*$)
```

Sample VBA code:

```
Sub REGEXP_TEST_UNIQUE()

Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim objMatches As MatchCollection

strInput = "123 456 789 123 456 789" 
strPattern = "([0-9]{3})(?!.*?\1.*$)"

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With

If regEx.test(strInput) Then
    Set objMatches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
    For i = 0 To objMatches.Count - 1
      Range("A2").Value = Range("A2").Value + " + " + objMatches.Item(i)
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

"A2" cell value becomes:

```
123 + 456 + 789
```